# Input is returning a zero

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do a little practicing on my own, combining elements of Jon Duckett's JavaScript and JQuery book with those of Treehouse's JavaScript Basics track. Basically the program allows someone to type in text and see how much it would cost to make a sign with that text.

When I try to copy the text from the input element and place it next to custom sign, my input.value returns a zero. Any help would be greatly appreciated with figuring this out

```js
var btnCalc = document.getElementById('myButton');
// Here's where I have the issue
var textInput = document.getElementById('textInput').value;

var customSign = document.getElementById('customSign');
var totalTiles = textInput.length;
var subtotal = totalTiles * 5;
var shipping = 7;
var grandTotal = subtotal + shipping;

btnCalc.addEventListener('click', Calculate);

function Calculate() {

    // and here
    document.getElementById('customSign').innerHTML = textInput;

    document.getElementById('totalTiles').textContent = totalTiles;

    document.getElementById('subtotal').textContent = subtotal;

    document.getElementById('shipping').textContent = shipping;

    document.getElementById('grandTotal').textContent = grandTotal;
}
```

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#right-col {
  float: right;
}

#left-col {
  float:left;
}

#input-form {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Duckett Chapter 2 Example</title>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet "type="text/css" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 id="greeting">Howdy Molly, please check your order: </h2>
        <div>
          <ul id="left-col">
            <li><span>Custom Sign: </span> </li>
            <li><span>Total Tiles: </span></li>
            <li><span>Subtotal: </span></li>
            <li><span>Shipping: </span></li>
            <li><span>Grand Total: </span></li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="right-col">
            <li id="customSign">Montague Hotel</li>
            <li id="totalTiles">14</li>
            <li id="subtotal">$70</li>
            <li id="shipping">$7</li>
            <li id="grandTotal">$77</li>
          </ul>
            <div id="input-form">
                <input id="textInput" type="text">
                <button id="myButton">Calculate</button>  
            </div>  
        </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables have to be inside your function, otherwise their values are already empty when you call it.

var btnCalc = document.getElementById('myButton');
btnCalc.addEventListener('click', Calculate);

```
function Calculate() {
  var textInput = document.getElementById('textInput').value;
  var customSign = document.getElementById('customSign');
  var totalTiles = textInput.length;
  var subtotal = totalTiles * 5;
  var shipping = 7;
  var grandTotal = subtotal + shipping;

  document.getElementById('customSign').innerHTML = textInput;
  document.getElementById('totalTiles').textContent = totalTiles;
  document.getElementById('subtotal').textContent = subtotal;
  document.getElementById('shipping').textContent = shipping;
  document.getElementById('grandTotal').textContent = grandTotal;
}
```

Comment: Lixus is right.  You just need to move those 5 lines from outside your Calculate function to inside your Calculate function.  Here's a fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/0v6bpkbv/

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way in JavaScript to define global variables? I'm used to writing in Java and I assumed the variables would be accessible by the functions.

Comment: The variables are accessible in the function but you have some logical errors because of the context of the variables outside of the function and then their context once it is called.

Comment: Technically it's what you did on your code, but their values are not kept after the script is done running, you will have to set them again inside your function when you call them.

Comment: Oh I see. So when the page loaded, the script ran. When the button was clicked, the script ran again but only the event listener ran and it had no way of knowing the variables that were stored in first part of the script. Is that close to correct?

Comment: Yes, so you would have to get the value of your text once again in order to get whatever your user typed in.

Answer (score 0):

Move calculation part to the function.

```js
var btnCalc = document.getElementById('myButton');
// Here's where I have the issue
var textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');
var customSign = document.getElementById('customSign');

btnCalc.addEventListener('click', Calculate);

function Calculate() {
    var totalTiles = textInput.value.length;
    var subtotal = totalTiles * 5;
    var shipping = 7;
    var grandTotal = subtotal + shipping;

    // and here
    document.getElementById('customSign').innerHTML = textInput.value;

    document.getElementById('totalTiles').textContent = totalTiles;

    document.getElementById('subtotal').textContent = subtotal;

    document.getElementById('shipping').textContent = shipping;

    document.getElementById('grandTotal').textContent = grandTotal;
}
```

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

span {
  font-weight: bold;
}

div {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#right-col {
  float: right;
}

#left-col {
  float:left;
}

#input-form {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Duckett Chapter 2 Example</title>
        <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet "type="text/css" >
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2 id="greeting">Howdy Molly, please check your order: </h2>
        <div>
          <ul id="left-col">
            <li><span>Custom Sign: </span> </li>
            <li><span>Total Tiles: </span></li>
            <li><span>Subtotal: </span></li>
            <li><span>Shipping: </span></li>
            <li><span>Grand Total: </span></li>
          </ul>
          <ul id="right-col">
            <li id="customSign">Montague Hotel</li>
            <li id="totalTiles">14</li>
            <li id="subtotal">$70</li>
            <li id="shipping">$7</li>
            <li id="grandTotal">$77</li>
          </ul>
            <div id="input-form">
                <input id="textInput" type="text">
                <button id="myButton">Calculate</button>  
            </div>  
        </div>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```